# What is the definition / what are the boundaries of "Mainland Mexico"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, méxico, solicitud-de-término, geografía

I am considering writing a series of "Best Places to Retire" books, with the first one being about Baja California.

If it goes well, I may follow up with one for Costa Rica, one for Panama, and one for the rest of Mexico (everything besides Baja).

Would it be fitting to call this (all of Mexico besides the two Bajas) "Mainland Mexico"?

It seems right, but the Baja Peninsula is actually connected to the rest of the Mexico, so I don't know if "Mainland Mexico" is an accurate way of describing that region. If not, what is the vast bulk of Mexico east of Baja called in Spanish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've heard it referred to as *México continental* when someone wants to distinguish the mainland from the Baja. As for English, "mainland Mexico" works and is attested.